# Reset password using custom authentication in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a custom authentication function and i also want to add reset password functionality.
So i added the reset button to login page and redirect it to change password page.

After this however i am confused as to how should i proceed to reset the password?

apex_util.reset_password->> will it help here?
I also need to update the new password with password in my table.
This is the custom auth function i am using.

Comment: I also hope you're hashing your passwords.

Comment: I agree with Scott, you should be hashing you're passwords. Mohamad Bouchi wrote about this recently here: https://tm-apex.blogspot.com/2020/03/custom-authentication-scheme-part1.html Personally, I like to store hashed passwords with a unique salt that's stored along with the password (colon delimited) to protect against rainbow tables. As for password reset, when you do custom authentication, you have to do that too. Typically, you show a "current" password field and then "new" and "confirm" password items. You have to validate the current password before doing the rest.

Comment: You should also consider some kind of "requires reset" column in your table. Then you can create an app-level process that redirects the user to the reset password page when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Vini,
The apex_util.change_password is to update APEX User credentials. You are storing user credentials in your own table. Therefore, you will need to write your own PL/QL to update the appropriate record in your table.
Regards,
David